# Why Is UITableViewController self.tableView Property Is Nil When Presented in UIPopoverController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController, nib based, that is presented in a UIPopoverController when running on iPad and presented 'natively' when running on iPhone.

When running on the iPad, the self.tableView property of the controller is nil throughout it's lifecycle. The delegate messages that pass in the tableView as part of their normal operation work fine and have a reference to a table view.

On the iPhone, the property is set and the reference is valid as you would expect.

Anything specific that can cause the self.tableView property to be nil? I've double checked the connections in Interface Builder - the Nib just contains a table view and the related UISearchBar stuff. The table view in the Nib is set as the view controller's view.

This is on 4.2.1 on both devices. Banging my head on this and can't find my error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out my problem and of course, it's a programming error.

In this case, an errant @synthesize tableView at the top of the implementation file, generating conflicting getters and setters.

Apologies and thanks for those that looked at this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... in one of the methods that returns the tableView object do "assert(self.view == tableView);" and see what happens. If the assert doesn't fire, and I suspect that it wont fire in either the iPhone or iPad, then simply cast self.view into a UITableView and do what you need to do.